# NumPy and SciPy give different answers for SVD of large matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, svd

I am trying to compute SVD of a large matrix A

```
A.shape
(36, 35388174)
```

Using scipy:

```
U,S,Vh = scipy.linalg.svd(A,full_matrices=False)

print(S)

[35210.38    23826.2     21697.746   17425.096   16549.27    15623.8
 15000.966   14357.92    14005.109   13129.836   13010.893   12615.829
 12383.197   12221.493   11679.343   11242.281   10814.762   10755.366
 10648.909   10311.2     10239.157   10083.088    9802.039    9550.317
  9420.9375   9381.448    9173.985    9041.382    8842.96     8652.94
  8535.361    8344.078    8099.3877   7820.099    7153.933     916.70636]
```

Using numpy:

```
u,s,vh = np.linalg.svd(A,full_matrices=False)

print(s)

[3.4531125e+04 2.3616658e+04 2.1767750e+04 1.7714088e+04 1.7016705e+04
 1.6240617e+04 1.5458729e+04 1.4844374e+04 1.4507225e+04 1.3558636e+04
 1.3446945e+04 1.3105698e+04 1.2979917e+04 1.2628450e+04 1.2211397e+04
 1.1814801e+04 1.1513952e+04 1.1406307e+04 1.1197293e+04 1.0896709e+04
 1.0791052e+04 1.0547981e+04 1.0336030e+04 1.0169862e+04 9.9821855e+03
 9.8735283e+03 9.6779170e+03 9.5541719e+03 9.4467988e+03 9.2135166e+03
 9.0191572e+03 8.9654697e+03 8.6382275e+03 8.4446582e+03 7.7426265e+03
 1.0030165e-01]
```

The singular values are not equal and the last singular value is 4 orders of magnitude smaller. Taking a look at u (from numpy) and U (from scipy):

```
print(u)
[[-0.0697393  -0.26300558  0.05060784 ... -0.00401564  0.08379341
   0.16666667]
 [-0.19386226 -0.16602474 -0.06390656 ...  0.12210891  0.01760345
   0.16666667]
 [ 0.00469474 -0.09212122 -0.1210581  ... -0.19498609 -0.18484618
   0.16666667]
 ...
 [-0.1298622   0.2572335  -0.01371225 ... -0.16663668 -0.04216435
   0.16666667]
 [ 0.11359861  0.00874646  0.0747335  ...  0.09103256 -0.10766056
   0.16666667]
 [-0.01117887  0.31221658 -0.02304421 ... -0.01541024  0.17811202
   0.16666667]]

print(U)
[[-0.06363079  0.24895889  0.06475112 ...  0.00938771 -0.08711426
   0.16206993]
 [-0.17853498  0.16458268 -0.05517053 ... -0.13653536 -0.02862898
   0.18436526]
 [ 0.00505272  0.09847414 -0.11075016 ...  0.18435302  0.19094269
   0.17114092]
 ...
 [-0.13527636 -0.26832885 -0.03441805 ...  0.1401335   0.04092857
   0.14420533]
 [ 0.1144547  -0.02642301  0.08755568 ... -0.08578777  0.10030627
   0.13807806]
 [-0.01411564 -0.33021146 -0.04248373 ...  0.03071252 -0.14734109
   0.13380453]]
```

Which aren't that close. Finally

```
print(vh@np.transpose(vh))
[[ 1.00000048e+00 -6.93247046e-07  1.12687985e-07 ... -2.09962352e-07
   3.96046680e-08 -6.66986466e-11]
 [-6.93247046e-07  9.99881804e-01  3.08433027e-06 ... -3.22498614e-08
   7.44651345e-08  3.53551499e-09]
 [ 1.12687985e-07  3.08433027e-06  9.99966562e-01 ... -6.02572925e-08
  -1.49726162e-07  7.28783434e-09]
 ...
 [-2.09962352e-07 -3.22498614e-08 -6.02572925e-08 ...  9.99996603e-01
   2.75532784e-07  4.71203521e-10]
 [ 3.96046680e-08  7.44651345e-08 -1.49726162e-07 ...  2.75532784e-07
   9.99986887e-01  3.10740234e-09]
 [-6.66986466e-11  3.53551499e-09  7.28783434e-09 ...  4.71203521e-10
   3.10740234e-09  9.99706209e-01]]
```

is something reasonably close to the Identity, whereas using the scipy result

```
print(Vh@np.transpose(Vh))
[[ 1.1432923e+00 -3.2717779e-03  9.4553661e-03 ...  4.3921277e-04
   8.4203773e-04  8.1602093e-03]
 [-3.2717779e-03  1.1259174e+00  5.1363837e-04 ... -2.4086710e-03
  -8.2119032e-06 -8.2697459e-02]
 [ 9.4553661e-03  5.1363837e-04  1.1285809e+00 ... -5.7055661e-04
   1.7901483e-03  5.5596817e-02]
 ...
 [ 4.3921277e-04 -2.4086710e-03 -5.7055661e-04 ...  1.1026798e+00
   2.3394339e-03  8.7424768e-03]
 [ 8.4203773e-04 -8.2119032e-06  1.7901483e-03 ...  2.3394339e-03
   1.0967851e+00  4.0833422e-04]
 [ 8.1602093e-03 -8.2697459e-02  5.5596817e-02 ...  8.7424768e-03
   4.0833422e-04  1.2048701e+00]]
```

which isn't really that close. Does anyone know what is going on? Any ideas how I can get a SVD that I can rely on, or is A just too big?

Comment: Maybe [this issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/13401)  can help